# Button Styles not applied when I deploy to Heroku

Tags: heroku, button, static, styles

I am trying to simply edit a style to the buttons on my simple slot machine application. When I apply the styles and run the app locally the styles are applied.

[Running App Locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEYuK.jpg)

But when I deploy to Heroku (and I should preface that I'm deploying using the PHP hack to upload to Heroku)

Every other style on from my styles css is running fine, but my button styles are not showing once deployed.

[App after deploying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baUh1.png)

below is my css code for reference

```
    color: #fff !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #41942c;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;  
}

button:hover {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```

Here is a link to my application for reference. https://lmp-slot-machine.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your button styles is applied see here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/utFMU.jpg

Comment: Hello, The photo you are refferring to is only showing when I run local host, my issue is when I deploy to Heroku the styles are not applied. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: If it's locally only then how did i get it? Check it again your style is working fine, try different browsers try different devices

Comment: I now see the styles being applied, it was a weird occurance when i opened it from then heroku browser site. Thank you!